Relation between the Gauß Integral and the gamma function
If one takes a more "generalised" form of the famos Gauß integral, you can show the following:
$$
G(q)=\int \limits_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x^{q}}dx
\\
u=x^q \implies \frac{du}{dx}=qx^{q-1}\implies dx=\frac{1}{q}u^{\frac{1}{q}-1}du
\\
G(q)=\frac{1}{q}\int \limits_{0}^{\infty}u^{\frac{1}{q}-1}e^{-u}du=\frac{1}{q}\Gamma(\frac{1}{q})
$$
1. Example: So for q=2 it follows that:
$$
G(2)=\frac{1}{2}\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \implies \Gamma(\frac{1}{2})=\sqrt{\pi}
$$
Using the functional equation for the Gamma function $\Gamma(n+1)=n\Gamma(n)$we get:
$$
\Gamma(n+\frac{1}{2})=\frac{(2n-1)!!}{2^{n}}\sqrt{\pi} \qquad \forall n \in \mathbb{N_0}
\\
\Gamma(\frac{1}{2}-n)=\frac{(-1)^{n}2^{n}}{(2n-1)!!}\sqrt{\pi} \qquad\forall n \in \mathbb{N_0}
$$
Those identities can be easily shown to be true via induction. It follows that:
$$
\Gamma(n+\frac{1}{2})=\frac{(-1)^n\pi}{\Gamma(\frac{1}{2}-n)}
\\
\Gamma(n+\frac{1}{2})\Gamma(\frac{1}{2}-n)=(-1)^n\pi
$$
Because of the given symmetry the identity holds $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$.
The double factorial just denotes:
$$
m!!=\prod \limits_{k=0}^{\lceil\frac{m}{2}\rceil-1}m-2k
$$
Note also that $(-1)!! = 1$, because:
$$
m!=m!!(m-1)!! \implies m!!=\frac{m!}{(m-1)!!} \implies m!!=\frac{(m+1)!}{(m+1)!!}
\\
(-1)!!=\frac{0!}{\frac{1!}{1!!}}=1
$$
Old Question:
So I now got two questions, are my calculations corret and if so do similar identities exist for larger values of $q$?
2. Addition/ Generalisation:
For the following i define:
$$
m!_a=\prod \limits_{k=0}^{\lceil\frac{m}{a}\rceil-1}m-ka
$$
Using the functional equation again, we get:
$$
f:\Gamma(n+\frac{1}{q})=\frac{(q(n-1)+1)!_q}{q^{n}}\Gamma(\frac{1}{q}) \qquad \forall n \in \mathbb{N_0}
\\
$$
To provide additional prove I will show that this identity holds via induction over $n$:
Base case for f: $(n=1)$
$$
\Gamma(1+\frac{1}{q})=\frac{1}{q}\Gamma(\frac{1}{q})\implies True
$$
Induction step for f: $(n\implies n+1)$
$$
\Gamma(n+1+\frac{1}{q})=(n+\frac{1}{q})\Gamma(n+\frac{1}{q})=(n+\frac{1}{q}) \frac{(q(n-1)+1)!_q}{q^{n}}\Gamma(\frac{1}{q})=\frac{(qn+1)!_q}{q^{n+1}}\Gamma(\frac{1}{q})\implies True
$$
For the second case $\Gamma(\frac{1}{q}-n)$ we cannot easily generalise the above mentioned equation, insead we derive a new one:
Reminder $\Gamma(m)=(m-1)\Gamma(m-1) \implies \frac{\Gamma(m)}{m-1}=\Gamma(m-1)$
$$
\Gamma(\frac{1}{q}-n)=\prod \limits_{k=0}^{n}(\frac{1}{q}-n+k)^{-1}\Gamma(\frac{1}{q})=\prod \limits_{k=0}^{n}(\frac{1-q(n+k)}{q})^{-1}\Gamma(\frac{1}{q})\\
=q^n(-1)^n\prod \limits_{k=0}^{n}(q(n-k)-1)^{-1}\Gamma(\frac{1}{q})=\frac{q^n(-1)^n}{(qn-1)!_q}\Gamma(\frac{1}{q})
$$
$$
g:\Gamma(\frac{1}{q}-n)=\frac{q^n(-1)^n}{(qn-1)!_q}\Gamma(\frac{1}{q})\qquad\forall n \in \mathbb{N_0}
$$
Unfortunately, since the equation $q(n-1)+1=qn-1 \implies q=2$ we just get for $q=2$ such a nice relation between $f$ and $g$.
New Question:
So having arrived at this point and assuming that what I just showed is indeed correct my new question is, how would I go about evaluating $G(q)$ for $q>2 $?

See this Wikipedia article. On the question about closed forms for  $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{q}\right)$, it's unlikely that you can find a nice closed form. The same article states that $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)$ is algebraically independent from $\pi$, which means no nice form in terms of $\pi$ is possible like in the case of $\Gamma\left(\frac12\right)$.
